# Election Day is upon us!

Tags: cipher, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram

> Some election mayhem! Any puzzlers here or regulars excited?

[image]

This is a picross or nonogram, for information about it and how to approach, please go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram).

Wanted to make my first short and easy original puzzle to celebrate election day (in the US).

FINAL EDIT: A confirmed solvable nonogram

Comment: Is it entirely solvable using only logic or do you have to make some guesses to solve it?

Comment: @gabbo1092 I think I answered your question in my answer lol

Comment: @kanoo yeah I made it where you were and wasn't sure if I was missing something

Comment: I'm not certain that you've got a solvable version yet. I kept hitting dead ends when I tried by hand, so I looked up an online solver, and... [It didn't like it](https://imgur.com/a/BS12sGX).

Comment: @benj2240 I guarantee you that it is solvable seeing as I solved it without a single guess. Remember to cross off spaces that you know are not possible and if you have, say, six blank spaces in a row and you know that four in a row inside it are filled, then the middle two must be two of the filled spaces. (_ _ x x _ _)

Comment: So I see... I'll have to give it another shot. Next time I'll hold off the "it's not possible" comment for a few extra minutes in case a solution is posted!

Comment: Oddly enough @benj2240 , I used that site to help make the solvable :) (and solved it by hand afterwards)

Comment: @jgibbers I thought it looked familiar ;) My apologies for casting doubt on this, it's a very good puzzle.

Comment: Your left-middle rows were off by a row. That might be why it says it's unsolvable

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the answer to your new and, as you said, solvable puzzle:
[image]

According to @boboquack's extremely generous hint in the comment:

> The symbols are flag semaphore. This means that the text translates to:
> GO
> VOTE

Ironically, I'm not American. Y'all listen to the OP anyway!

Comment: Agreed about the guesswork.  I don't think you can even safely say that 4 in the "middle" are in that location and not the four open spots to the right..

Comment: @Greg You're right about that, it was the one guess/chance that I took, I'm too lazy to change it if I'm not gonna solve it either way tho

Comment: Fair.  Wasn't chiding you, just pointing out (further) that it can't be solved without LOTS of guessing :-\

Comment: Oh no, I made sure it was logically solvable before I missed the few additional columsn in the first picture, but didn't check the second one. I'm going to vote to close this, until I have time to rework it again.

Comment: Kanoo and @Greg Since I couldn't delete the puzzle, I updated it to have colors and pre filled squares, and I've confirmed its solvable. Again, sorry this was absolutely my mistake

Comment: Cool!  I probably won't get around to solving this one in time, but I'm going to look into these types of puzzles more as they seem interesting!

Comment: That's half of it! Check the tags (and maybe the top flavor text again)

Comment: Hint: look up (rot13) Synt frzncuber

Comment: I'm glad I was able to award you the check mark! Especially after fumbling the first couple of times, bounty will be coming as an apology shortly. The flavor text was a hidden rot13(npebfgvp) for the hint @boboquack gave you. 

The next puzzle will be tighter! I just really love nonograms, and wish they were used more in puzzles.

Comment: @JGibbers I agree, they're typically on the easy side but they're so relaxing to solve.